# indexing the last dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two images called image and mask with the following shapes:

```
image shape: (876, 1020, 3)
mask shape: (876, 1020)
```

What I am trying to do is divide each of the three elements of image with the mask where the mask is non-zero. So, I do:

```
import numpy as np

index = np.nonzero(mask)
image[index, :] = image[index, :]/mask[index]
```

This however causes the program to take a long time and then it fails with;

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,302793,1020,3) (302793,)

Comment: Have you played with this calculation in an interactive Python shell with smaller arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have memory problems with the creation of a copy of the mask, you could set the zero elements to 1 and divide through directly:

```
mask2 = mask.copy()
mask2[mask2==0]=1
image /= mask2[...,np.newaxis]
```